# Limmiting solution of $Ax=b$ to positive quantities

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

My personal trainer put me on a diet recently which has had me tracking the macro-nutrients that I eat i.e. protein, carbohydrates and fat. I am supposed to eat a specific amount each meal and eat five meals a day. As you might imagine planning meals so that they fit this diet is time consuming and not so much fun.

So I decided to write a little program that would plan my meals for me. I would have a data base of foods and recipes that would each have a vector representation where the components are the macro-nutrients protein, carbohydrates and fat (in grams). I could randomly select some foods stick their vector representations together into an $A$ matrix and then use a library with an $Ax=b$ solver to figure out how much of each food I should eat.

However, it didn't work as well as I had hoped. I get results that say things like eat 0.2363 grams of almonds and drink -5 cups of milk. The tiny amount of almonds I can just throw away or round up programmatically. What I don't know how to deal with is the -5 cups of milk. **How do I limit the solutions of $Ax=b$ to positive quantities only?**

It probably doesn't matter but I am writing this in python and using [this function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) to solve for $x$:

> Return the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation.
>
> Solves the equation a x = b by computing a vector x that minimizes the >Euclidean 2-norm || b - a x ||^2. The equation may be under-, well-, or >over- determined (i.e., the number of linearly independent rows of a can be >less than, equal to, or greater than its number of linearly independent >columns). If a is square and of full rank, then x (but for round-off error) >is the “exact” solution of the equation.

Comment: You'd probably want to use a non-negative least squares solver.  Possibly try [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html)?

Comment: It seems like your question is more to the effect of "If $Ax=b$ is an overdetermined system of equations, how can I find a suitable solution?" - because, as it is, one can solve $Ax=b$ (or find the set of solutions), but if that's not suitable, there's no wiggle-room - you might try editing some more details about your current methods into the question, because I think they are very useful information to would-be answerers.

Comment: How many rows and columns does $A$ have? Because, if the number of columns is not strictly greater than the number of rows, the *exact* solution of $Ax=B$ is most likely unique. I don't know about the method proposed by @aepound though. It seems he's suggesting an approximate method which might work.

Comment: I could change how this works but there are typically three or more foods in a meal so if $A$ is $m$x$n$ then $m=3$ and $n>=3$. The example I am playing with has four foods.

Comment: @aepound [that](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) function does what I wanted! thanks :)

Comment: Thankyou for posting and solving this. I have a very similar problem (needs to be fast, flexible to matrix sizes but can be approximate, elements of A and b can have any value) being implemented in .NET. I am currently solving using Accord.NET's Matrix.Solve but need to introduce this same positive x constraint. @aepound or user3810695, please could post your code as I haven't been able to track down a full copy of the book online.

Comment: @jt78 you'd probably want to find a good reference for non-negative least squares.  The answer below just happened to be for the language the OP was using. Google to find out about it, or read up on it on the [Wikipedia nnls article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, you seem to be looking for a solution that enforces positivity constraints on the resultant $x$ vector.

The python function [scipy.optimize.nnls](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) is one implementation of non-negative least squares and might do what you're looking for.